# jinja2 how to remove trailing newline

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, newline

I'm using jinja 2 to output a yaml file but can't seem to get rid of a trailing newline and the end of a for loop. Eg the below

```
 - request:
        path: {{ path }}
        headers:
          origin: 'somedomain.com'
          user-agent: 'agent'
          referer: 'some.domain.com'
          authority: 'somedomain.com'
        querystring:
          {% for key, value in querystring.items() -%}
          {{ key }}: '{{ value }}'
          {% endfor %}
      response:
        content:
          file: {{ content }}
```

gives me the output:

```
- request:
    path: /some/path
    headers:
      origin: 'somedomain.com'
      user-agent: 'agent'
      referer: 'somedomain.com'
      authority: 'somedomain.com'
    querystring:
      postcode: 'xxxxxx'
      houseNo: '55'

  response:
    content:
      file: address.json
```

With an additional unwanted blank line after houseNo.    How do I get rid of this line?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Change your loop to strip whitespace from the top AND bottom of the output (notice extra `-` at the `for` loop close):

```py
{% for key, value in querystring.items() -%}
  {{ key }}: '{{ value }}'
{%- endfor %}
```

In my tests (using https://github.com/abourguignon/jinja2-live-parser), the `-` must come after the first `{%`, not before the last to achieve what you're asking for.

Docs: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Prepending the `-` instead of appending preserves the indentation and does not screw up the spaces in the next line.

Comment: Correct, I didn't remember this detail until I played around with it again.

Comment: For me, this puts all the key: value pairs on a single line. I don't understand why this answer was accepted.

Comment: Just because I didn't see this part of the explanation anywhere, I figured I'd add it. Putting a `-` before the second percent sign on the first line of the for loop removes newlines before the added line. Putting a `-` after the first percent sign on the last line of the for loop removes newlines after the added line. Combine them both, and you get 0 newlines. Have only one, and you only get a newline to separate a line, but not an extra newline between each line. In my case, I wanted a newline before the loop but not after each element, so I put the `-` before the `endfor`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 26):

I think you can get rid of it using the [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) feature. Thus I would modify the `endfor` block to `{% endfor -%}`

See if that does it!

Answer (score 13):

For those using Flask who arrive here, these lines did the trick for me:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.lstrip_blocks = True
app.jinja_env.trim_blocks = True
```

Comment: Maybe you could make your answer more generic by explaining that you can set it in the Environment object: `Environment(trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)`

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is only half of the solution, because it removes **all** newlines.

You can avoid the trailing newline by first removing all newlines (using the minus signs at `-%}` and `{%-` in the for loop), and then inserting the desired newlines at the right place (using the `loop.last` condition).

The following templates renders a dictionary, d, to as JSON text:

```
{
    {% for key, value in d.items() -%}
    "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"{{ ",
    " if not loop.last }}
    {%- endfor %}
}
```

For `d = {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}`, the template renders to

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to solve this problem:

```
- request:
    path: {{ path }}
    headers:
      origin: 'somedomain.com'
      user-agent: 'agent'
      referer: 'some.domain.com'
      authority: 'somedomain.com'
    querystring: >-
      {% for key, value in querystring.items() -%}
      {{ key }}: '{{ value }}'
      {% endfor %}
  response:
    content:
      file: {{ content }}
```

- `>`, `|`: "clip": keep the line feed, remove the trailing blank lines.
- `>-`, `|=`: "strip": remove the line feed, remove the trailing blank lines.
- `>+`, `|+`: "keep": keep the line feed, keep trailing blank lines.

Thx **Steve Bennett**'s post:
[In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210)

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me fix my issue, how ever the correct operator i had to use is "|-" (pipe minus), now my multi line string is correctly transported to my json files, with all line ending except the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress rendering of the below lines:

```
<% for ... %>
<% endfor %>
<% if ... %>
<% endif %>
```

by setting trim_blocks=True and lstrip_blocks=True in your jinja2 environment. See the example below, info from [their docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control)

```
context = {'querystring': querystring, 'path': path, 'content': content}    
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates/'),
    trim_blocks=True,
    lstrip_blocks=True
)
print(jinja_env.get_template('my_template.yaml').render(context))
```