# Unable to get new lines with "\n" from template to actual output using jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to generate an xml file with `jinja2` module using a `template`. Somehow I am not able to get new line with `\n` from template to actual output.

This is xml-template.xml:

```
<module>
    <group name="abc">
        <subinst entity="x" id="0" />
        {% for n in range(count) %}<subinst entity="y"    id="{{n}}" />\n {% endfor %}
    </group>
</module>
```

This is my script:

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader
count = 3
file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader, keep_trailing_newline=True)
template = env.get_template('xml-template.xml')
output = template.render(count=count)
print(output)
```

When I run my script, I get `\n` as it is instead of new lines in the output as below.

This is my expected output:

```
<module>
    <group name="abc">
        <subinst entity="x" id="0" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="0" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="1" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="2" />
    </group>
</module>
```

I tried using `<br>` (which is true for `HTML`), tried using `keep_trailing_newline=True` but nothing seems to help.

Can someone help me fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for a *very* well-written question with example code and expected output.

I got this to work using this template (ensure tabs and spaces are consistent in this file):

```
<module>
    <group name="abc">
        <subinst entity="x" id="0" />
        {% for n in range(count) %}
        <subinst entity="y" id="{{n}}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </group>
</module>
```

And this environment (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165000/42346):

```
env = Environment(loader=file_loader,lstrip_blocks=True,trim_blocks=True)
```

Example:

```
In [84]: print(output)
<module>
    <group name="abc">
        <subinst entity="x" id="0" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="0" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="1" />
        <subinst entity="y" id="2" />
    </group>
</module>
```